# Kohana query builder

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-db, kohana-3.0

i am building query in kohana framework which looks like this:

```
DB::select('users.email')->from('users', 'roles_users')->
where('users.id', '=', 'roles_users.user_id')->
and_where('roles_users.role_id', '=', '2');
```

it would output:

```
SELECT `users`.`email` FROM `users`, `roles_users` 
WHERE `users`.`id` = 'roles_users.user_id' 
AND `roles_users`.`role_id` = '2'
```

so my problem is that kohana puts `' '` for me on `roles_users.user_id` so mysql searches for text not for actual value of the field. is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason you are not joining the other table? Like that:

```
DB::select('users.email')
->from('users')
->join('roles_users', 'LEFT')
->on('users.id', '=', 'roles_users.user_id')
->where('roles_users.role_id', '=', '2');
```

If you don't like that, try

```
DB::select('users.email')
->from('users', 'roles_users')
->where('users.id', '=', DB::expr('roles_users.user_id'))
->and_where('roles_users.role_id', '=', '2');
```

Comment: Obviously first snippet is the solution. But I am wondering, whether it is possible to do using second snippet. there will not be any join, so how db will understand `where('users.id', '=', DB::expr('roles_users.user_id'))`?

Comment: DB::expr('blablabla') means that 'blablabla' isn't escaped by query builder.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with `DB::expr()`?